# How can I save widget's data to device in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

when a file add I want to do an easy way to access that file in my app. to do that I am using ListView.builder() widget. but I can't save the data in the app
I worked on the shared_preferences package. At least I don't know how I must do

Comment: Create a model class, store data by that model. Then you'd be able to build your screen, by ListView builder appropriate by that stored data.

Comment: make a model and put it type list and convert this list in json and then store in share prefernce after get it from shared prefrence and decode the json and map it to your model again and use it in listview builder................smile now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this block, I am using ListviewBuilder to create widgets so I needed an array. after this, I wanted to save this data on my device. I am using shared preferences but shared preferences only allow to add string array. then, I decoded all arrays to String array then, when I start the widget in initstate. I take data then, encode the array data then, add value to my variable.

```dart
SharedPreferences? sharedPref;
List<Map<String, dynamic>> documents = [];
List<String> documentsEncode = [];

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getInstance();
  }

 Future<void> getInstance() async {
    final sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    documentsEncode = sharedPref.getStringList(widget.collection!) ?? [];
    documentsEncodeToDecode();
    // main();
  }

 documentsEncodeToDecode() {
    documents.clear();
    documentsEncode.forEach((documentEncode) {
      Map<String, dynamic> document = jsonDecode(documentEncode);
      documents.add(document);
    });
    setState(() {});
  }
```